# jQuery transport.send requestHeaders possibly SSL issue

Tags: jquery, ssl, xmlhttprequest

I have two sites with identical codebases. The sites are both SSL. All links to resources are on the same domain and always accessed using a full https path.

The problem I have is that one server has no errors, whilst the other displays:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This error is in `jQuery-1.11.1.js`, where undefined is the var `e`. The pertinent code is here:

```
        try {
            state = 1;
            transport.send( requestHeaders, done );                                                                              
        } catch ( e ) {
            // Propagate exception as error if not done
            if ( state < 2 ) {
                done( -1, e );
            // Simply rethrow otherwise
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

The only difference between the two that I can see is that if I `console.log` the var `requestHeaders` on the domain that works I get

```
Object {Accept: "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01", X-Requested-With: "XMLHttpRequest"}
Object {Accept: "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01", X-Requested-With: "XMLHttpRequest"}
```

whilst on the domain that doesn't work I get:

```
Object {Accept: "*/*", X-Requested-With: "XMLHttpRequest"} 
Object {Accept: "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01", X-Requested-With: "XMLHttpRequest"} 
Object {Accept: "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01", X-Requested-With: "XMLHttpRequest"}
```

The difference being the first accepted parameter, which is present when it doesn't work.

I am making calls using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://domain.com/index.php?id=xxx',
    type:'get',
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(data){

            }
});
```

Can anyone help me shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have @RequestBody json as a parameter to the method you are trying to send the ajax request. I got this error and my tech stack is Spring Java and usual UI technologies.

And this bug has been closed by JQuery 
https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14852